# Why are both of my graphs not showing when using Altair on Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, altair

Code for two graphs. Ran this code a couple of times, and for some reason all that's showing up is the histogram. It's also important to mention that I am using Spyder IDE as well, if that makes any difference. Oh....and I've also tried graph|hist... but nothing

```
    import altair as alt
    import pandas as pd
   
    #import csv
    acs = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Andrew/anaconda3/mydata/acs2020.csv')
    acs.head()
    
    
    interval = alt.selection_interval()

    #build point graph
    graph = alt.Chart(acs).mark_point(opacity=1).encode(
        x = ('Trade #'),
        y = ('Balance'),
        color = alt.Color('Item',scale=alt.Scale(scheme='tableau10')),
        tooltip = [alt.Tooltip('Type'),
                   alt.Tooltip('Profit'),
                   alt.Tooltip('Ticket:N')
                  ]
    ).properties(
        width = 900
    )

    #build histogram
    hist = alt.Chart(acs).mark_bar().encode(
        x = 'count()',
        y = 'Item',
        color = 'Item'
    ).properties(
        width = 800,
        height = 80
    ).add_selection(
        interval
    )
    #show graphs
    graph&hist.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for joining stack overflow. One of the requirements for a post is that it should be easily reproducible for those looking at it. Right now you are linking to a file that is inside of your local computer. This makes it hard for any of us to reproduce the issue.  I would recommend creating a minimum reproducible example of the graph you are trying to make with an open source dataset that you can pull in from github or a package like seaborn. This will likely improve your response rate a ton.

Comment: Ok, duly noted. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to the last line: `(graph & hist).show()`.

---

Explanation: when you write something like

```python
graph&hist.show()
```

Python dictates the order of operations, and method calls have higher precedence than binary operators. This means that it is equivalent to:

```python
(graph) & (hist.show())
```

You are showing the `hist` chart, and then concatenating the return value of the `show()` method, which is `None`, to the `graph` chart, which will result in a `ValueError` when the histogram chart is closed.

Instead, if you want to show the result of the `graph & hist` operation, you need to use parentheses to indicate this:

```python
(graph & hist).show()
```